# Magento Enterprise Edition takes too much time loading customer page and catalog page

Tags: mysql, magento, optimization, enterprise

Hello experts please help.
I'm having problem fixing opening customers page and catalog page which takes too much time to open the page.
Here are the details of the site:
-Magento Enterprise platform
-Having around one million of registered customer in the database
-Having around 10 thousand of products in the catalog page

The most much time consuming to load is the customers page which have around 1 million registered customer in the database. Please help by providing your suggestions on how to fix.
Maybe the problem is related to database because of large amount of data then what are the best steps to do?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimizing your MySQL configuration (your my.cnf file) could improve the performance of your site. The following is the configuration that some colleagues and I have used with success (adjust according to the resources available to you). Of particular importance, I think, are the innodb_buffer_pool_size and query_cache_size.

```
max_connections = 500
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
key_buffer_size = 768M
join_buffer_size = 4M
read_buffer_size = 4M
read_rnd_buffer_size=16M
sort_buffer_size = 8M
table_cache = 1224
thread_cache_size = 32
wait_timeout = 100
interactive_timeout = 100
connect_timeout = 100
tmp_table_size = 256M
max_heap_table_size = 128M
max_allowed_packet = 2M
max_connect_errors = 999999999
thread_concurrency = 8
query_cache_limit = 2M
query_cache_size = 256M
query_cache_type = 1
query_prealloc_size = 16384
query_alloc_block_size = 16384
skip-name-resolve
expire_logs_days = 7
log-slow-queries        = /var/log/mysqld.slow.log
innodb_thread_concurrency = 16
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=20M
innodb_log_file_size = 384M
```